Retrieving the "Custom Label" or "SKU" field from an eBay listing via eBay API
I'm attempting to use the eBay API to retrieve the "Custom Label" or "SKU" field from a listing after it's been sold so I can incorporate it with my accounting software to create appropriate invoices and such. I can successfully retrieve the SKU field by using eBay's 'Shopping' API with the GetSingleItem call. However, this API I believe is deprecated and I read somewhere that it's going to be removed sometime in 2025. They recommend using the 'Browse' API instead. The issue is the browse API doesn't appear to return the SKU field no matter what I do using the GetItem call.
The endpoint I've been using is https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item/{item_id} and I tried using various URL params they suggest to retrieve additional info but none of them I've tried have included a SKU. I tried ?fieldgroups=PRODUCT ?fieldgroups=ADDITIONAL_SELLER_DETAILS and ?fieldgroups=COMPACT and none include the SKU. Am I missing something here? I keep going over the docs and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong
Open to any suggestions. Only other alternative solution I can come up with is including my internal item number/SKU and appending it to the end of the title for all of my listings. Then in my script pulling the SKU out of the title and using that as the SKU in my accounting software. This seems less than ideal and not the best for SEO so I would like to avoid it if possible.
